# Simplest Media Query to add a background color not working?

Tags: css, media-queries

I feel like a complete idiot...

This is the simplest of things but it doesn't work in any browser with the exception of Firefox.

I'm declaring it in the head / style section of the html

Any help will be greatly appreciated - CES

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    body{
        background-color: red;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its working fine bro: https://jsfiddle.net/75uLyfvw/

Comment: Well I figured out where the problem was but now I have a new question... The problem was I was using the Inspect (ctl + shift + i) / toggle device emulation in the browser to see Device specific breakpoints. Any other way it works but NOT in the one place it should work. Any clue as to why??

Comment: Would you care to tell us where is the ONE PLACE?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the head and a missing meta tag... in order for you to use the Developer Tools Device Spacific breakpoints in Chrome, Edge and Safari you MUST include:

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"

While it works without including it when you View the page in the browser, in order to use the Developer Tools it has to be in the head.